# How do I make search function only look in post content (not in the title)

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently when users search something in my wordpress blog the search function checks whether the search term is on the title or content. I need to have a search function which only checks the searched term in posts content.

I don't know where is the original code of the search function in wordpress...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to show the title results only on your search page.

you can delete out `<?php the_content(); ?>` from the `search.php page`

does that do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM prod_table WHERE field_content LIKE '%$content%';
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I'm a total noob at web design. In which part of my code do I include that?

Comment: You are showing the code that displays the form. The search function is in the code that receives the form submission (maybe it is called `index.php` ?).

Comment: It isn't in index.php nor in any of the theme files. If if find it can I create a second search function to search just in content? I need the original search funtion to remain as it is. I'll try to find it and post it when I do.